# Responsive design using @media to change height

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries, responsive

I'm using @media method to change `#services` div height once the screen resizing to 600px width.
but for some reason the div height doesn't change and he remains the same.

I'm using grid to change `.service` divs position once screen is resizing, but when they align downwards the `#services` div doesn't change his height. I believe he should be changing once `@media` get activated.

The grid to change service classes once screen resizing:

```
.container-grid {
    margin-left: 17%;
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 30px;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, 350px);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 400px);
}
```

The @media to change `#services` height once screen resizing to auto height:

```
#services {
  padding-top: 100px;
  background-color: #000;
  height: 600px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  z-index: 0;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  #services {
    height: auto;
  }
}
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/yotking789/full/ZEYqbWq)

How can I change `#services` height from 600px to auto height once screen width changes?

Comment: Its working in your Fiddle.. https://codepen.io/yotking789/pen/ZEYqbWq

Comment: @Kevin you should switch to full page to see it

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website OR off-site example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: No, actually I clicked in your codepen link and checked it by dragging the window.

Comment: I couldn't get this to work in Codepen either...I think it's an issue there since it works in JSFiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/kr8z5pb0/